# JPA Repository methods are not decapitalize attribute names when attribute name contains a preceding single letter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

We are facing a problem creating some JPA repository methods following the naming conventions of JPA.
Our entity is

```
@Entity(name = "regcmp_document")
@Table(name = "regcmp_document")
@NamedQuery(name = "RegcmpDocument.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM regcmp_document r")
public class RegcmpDocument implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "i_regcmpdoc_id")
    private Long iRegcmpdocId;

    @Column(name = "i_regsec_id")
    private String iRegsecId;

    public Long getIRegcmpdocId() {
        return this.iRegcmpdocId;
    }

    public void setIRegcmpdocId(Long iRegcmpdocId) {
        this.iRegcmpdocId = iRegcmpdocId;
    }

    public String getIRegsecId() {
        return this.iRegsecId;
    }

    public void setIRegsecId(String iRegsecId) {
        this.iRegsecId = iRegsecId;
    }
}
```

and the repository we are trying to create is

```
@Repository
public interface RegcmpDocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<RegcmpDocument, Long> {
    RegcmpDocument findByiRegcmpdocIdAndIRegsecId(Long regcmpdocId, String iRegsecId);
}
```

The problem is that all columns, including these two, as well all attributes in our project are generated though automated tool that gave them these kind of names (following database column names).
The error that we get after jpa validation is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [IRegsecId] on this ManagedType [gr.neurosoft.factoring.entities.RegcmpDocument]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:43)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:635)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:619)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.getTypedPath(JpaQueryCreator.java:385)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:308)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.and(JpaQueryCreator.java:133)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.and(JpaQueryCreator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:122)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:217)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:348)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:91)
```

After some investigation I realized that the decapitalize of Java.Bean.Introspector is used and when two first letters of an attribute are uppercase then it returns name as is.

My question is if we can override somehow this method and hint JPA to use a custom one?
If not ,can we configure jpa to handle this columns differently?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The method name might need to be: findByiRegcmpdocIdAndiRegsecId.  By why not spell out whatever iRegcmpdocId and iRegsecId actually mean?

Comment: @AndrewS or check the log to check to what names the columns are being mapped. First better to remove `findByiRegcmpdocIdAndIRegsecId` though

Comment: Yep, even though the schema is autogenerated, it doesn't mean that your java code has to follow suit.  You can do something like `@Column(name = "i_regsec_id")
    private String regSecId;`

Comment: @AndrewS thanks for you comment, the findByiRegcmpdocIdAndiRegsecId doesn't work either. JPA thinks then that "and" is an attribute. Yes you are right these should be written differently from the start but now whole project i like so. I am looking for a way to not rewrite all the entities

Comment: @lane.maxwell thanks for your comment. Yes this is what i am planning to do if i do not find any other solution . All entities should be written this way from the beginning. Either way, before doing that i am still searching to override/customize the decapitalize method of Java.beans.Introspector.

Comment: What do your getters and setters look like for these fields?  There's no reason why spring data jpa can't work with these.

Comment: @lane.maxwell added the setters and getters to the original post.Thanks

Comment: After some more investigation I made sure that during evaluation of parameters and query parsing from JPA inside the org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part , Introspector.decapitalize is used and as a built in function does not uncapitalize a part which starting with 2 first characters CAPS. I didn't find any way to hint JPA to use a custom decapitalize as well as nothing on the Internet about it. So this seems to me as a JPA limitation/restriction that Entities cannot have camelCase variables with preceding single letter. Seems that we need to change all entities.